# PostgreSQL doesn't find function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I have the following PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LogIn (username_in varchar(64), pswd_in varchar(64))
RETURNS integer AS 
DECLARE
    pswd varchar(64);
    retval integer; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT pswd INTO pswd
    FROM User
    WHERE username = username_in;

    IF pswd IS NULL THEN
        retval = 1;
    ELSIF pswd <> pswd_in THEN
        retval = 2;
    ELSE
        retval = 3;
    END IF;

    RETURN retval;
END;
```

Here you can see the function is correctly stored in pgAdmin:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qHiA.png

but when I try to call it from psql I get an error saying the function does not exist, and it doesn't matter how I pass the parameters to it.

I have another function too and that one works. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: When you call it you should quote the name: `"LogIn"( 'aa', 'bb');` Or better: avoid mixed cased identifiers.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you so much, now it works even though not like it should hahaha, but at least it's a step forward.  May I ask why I have to quote the name when I call this function but the other one works without quotes?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS